# Django - Include app template in base template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I trying to include app result in base template. Template is displayed properly but I don't see any results. When I open app url directly (127.0.0.1/Project/config/) it show results.

Project / urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'Project.views.index'),
    url(r'^config/', DisplayChangelog),
)
```

config / views.py

```
from config.models import Changelog

def DisplayChangelog(request):
    changes = Changelog.objects.all()
    t = loader.get_template("changelog.html")
    c = Context({'changes': changes})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

templates / base.html

```
...
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
{% include "changelog.html" %}
</ul>
...
```

templates / changelog.html

```
...
{% for change in changes %}
<li class="media">
    <div class="body">
    {{ change.desc }}
    <div class="date">{{ change.date }}</div>
    </div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting to see. The template is rendered with information at /config/, which is what you expect. It won't work from any other paths.

Comment: I would like to include this results in base template, because I want to see this changes on any subpage included in box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to put some variables in your `base.html` if you use them on every single page, but also you have to pass these variables somehow. Of course you won't add one more object to the context in each view so there is an idea of [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). Take a look at the docs if this is really what you need.

In your case, I think it's just enough to add a `changes` variable to the `index` view's context and include your `changelog` in the template rendered by `index` view.

So basically I want to say that you have to pass objects to the view's context if you want to use them in your templates, even if you use them in included templates.

Comment: But index views shows one of subpages. In this case dashboard.html. I would like to include changelog.html in header of base.html

Comment: I looked a closer context_processors.

I changed config / views.py at:
`def DisplayChangelog(request):
    return {'changes': Changelog.objects.all()}`

and put variable on index view:
`{% include "changelog.html" with changes=changes %}`

Thank you

Comment: @user3041764 yes, that's what you needed to do. Besides, you don't need to  write `with changes=changes` as `changes` variable is included in your global context object now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this after you define  "changes" variable in your view:

`{% include "changelog.html" with changes=changes %}`

Comment: I combine it with context_processors and it gives a result what I need. Thank you